# Build failed: Building for 'IOS-simulator', but linking in object file

Tags: ios, react-native

Building for 'iOS-simulator', but linking in object file (/Users/(username)/clientProject/(foldername)/ios/Pods/GoogleMaps/Maps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework/GoogleMaps) built for 'iOS'
I have already tried adding 'arm64' in exclued architecture but it still doesn't work.
xcode version is 15.00 so can't open it with rosseta as well
Can anybody please kindly help?